# What type of google database for a deals based website?

Tags: sql, database-design, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to find out what makes the most sense for my type of database structure.

A breakdown of what it is and what I intend to do is.

A deals based website using strong consistency that will be needing to update existing linked foreign keys to new parents in a scenario where an alias such as 'Coke' is not linked up to its actual data 'Coca-Cola'.

I will be creating a price over time for these products and should be able to handle large amounts of data with little performance issues over time.

I initially began with Google's BigTable but quickly realised that without a relational part of it, it will fail on any cascading updates.

I don't want to spend plenty of time researching and learning all of these different types to later realise it isn't what I wanted. The most important aspect for me is the cascading update and ensuring it can handle a vertically large data structure for the price over time trends.

Additionally, because this is from scratch, I would be more interested in price and scalability than existing compatibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Cloud SQL is a fully-managed database service that makes it easy to
>   set up, maintain, manage, and administer your relational PostgreSQL
>   BETA and MySQL databases in the cloud. Cloud SQL offers high
>   performance, scalability, and convenience. Hosted on Google Cloud
>   Platform, Cloud SQL provides a database infrastructure for
>   applications running anywhere.

check this out it might help - https://cloud.google.com/sql/

Answer (score 0):

[Googles Cloud SQL service](https://cloud.google.com/sql/) provides a fully managed relational database service. It supports PostgreSQL and MySQL.

Google also provides the [Cloud Spanner service](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/). It also provides a fully managed relational database service. Additionally Cloud Spanner provides a distributed relational database. It is better suited for mission critical systems.